# How to NOT turn element read only when waiting for '#ajax' callback in Drupal 7 forms?

Tags: forms, ajax

I need a simple `'#type' => 'textfield'` field. When a user types in it, I want to update another section of my form. Just a more elaborate version of built-in autocomplete field, really. So I added:

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'mymodule_tag',
  'wrapper' => 'edit-tags',
  'method' => 'replace',
  'effect' => 'fade',
  'event' => 'input',
),
```

The only problem is - it turns my field disabled when waiting for the server's reaction. This is unacceptable: User's input should never be blocked, that's a priority. I bet the solution is simple, but googling for it gives me a lot of results about how to disable field, and none about keeping it enabled. Too much noise for my search skills. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree with your premise (interesting question, nonetheless). If performing a second operation while the first is already running would cause a problem client/server side, then that operation should definitely be blocked in my opinion.

If the only issue you have is that the blocking is done by way of disabling the text field, consider that it's just a matter of good UX. If the field wasn't disabled, but the functionality *was*, then there's no feedback to the user, who is left wondering why nothing's happening even though they're typing into a text field that has some rich functionality a few seconds earlier.

That said, if you want to override the behaviour of Drupal's AJAX have a look in the /misc/ajax.js file. You'll need to re-implement at least:

- `Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend`
- `Drupal.ajax.prototype.success`
- `Drupal.ajax.prototype.error`

Those functions set/remove the `disabled` attribute on the element. It should be reasonably straight forward to re-assign those functions in a custom JS file, and you can just remove lines like this:

```
$(this.element).addClass('progress-disabled').attr('disabled', true);
```

Or tweak it to something more palatable for your use case.

Comment: Operations are read-only and cacheable. It's just a fancy selective autocomplete, that's all. So there is no problem with race conditions and alike. And I don't want to override behaviour for every field on my site. I just need it on one field.
I hoped there is something like '#nonblocking' parameter for '#ajax' table I'm simply unable to find. Looking at those files, I guess that's not the case.

Comment: For blocking - there is a rotating ball or other icon indicating ajax at work. That should be enough for most users to see that they're supposed to wait for their results.

Comment: @Mołot I would class that as bad UX - The "should be enough" icon doesn't cut it for me, you're making the assumption that your users will have exactly the same thought process as you (believe me, that's almost never the case!) and that they'll automatically know that the rotating icon means they can't use the textfield for the same purpose until the icon is gone. I'd imagine that's one of the reasons the functionality you're looking for was never implemented - it's not seen as the right way to do things. Either way, though, at least you've got a way forward if it matters enough :)

Comment: But they CAN use the textfield. Just like they CAN write in regular autocomplete form element for tags, even if ajax is waiting for autocomplete suggestions to return from a server. My case is just a bit more elaborate autocomplete, but with the same UX basis. So, it actually WAS implemented, just in a way that makes it hard to tailor to a bit more advanced needs.

Comment: I don't think we're going to agree, I'm looking at it from a different perspective. I sympathise though, I've been at odds with the 'accepted' way of doing things before and had to work hard to get around what I consider bad-practice, even though the majority (or, the core developers at least) disagree.

Comment: Well, I can't see a reason why autocomplete works the way it does and it's OK, but when I need to build something that works the same way, just puts it's results in a div I choose instead, and with more elaborate suggestions, it's suddenly a bad practice.

Comment: You're just going to have accept that you're coding against a framework, and that you might not always agree with the methods/implementations/decisions of that framework (I know I don't!). Something that may not work for your use case may work perfectly well for 99.99% of other cases. Or it might not, and you might be describing what many would see as a bug. Who's to say. The developers have been careful to make sure all behaviour like this can be overridden if it's not to your liking, though, so I think the problem, if any, is a tiny one